# Tkinter not recognizing classes when using command argument in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to make a little window with buttons in Tkinter
Running a Python version 3.7.4

using "command= " when a object is not in a class did work though

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

class enemy:
    life = 100
    def attack(self):
        self.life -= 10
        print('ouchhh') or print('arghhh')

    def checklife(self):
        if life <= 0:
            print("im dead")
        else:
            print('the enemy has' , self.life)



master.geometry('200x200')
master.title('game')

attackbutton = Button(master,text='Attack',bg="black",fg='White',command=attack)
attackbutton.pack()

checklifebutton = Button(master,text='Check enemy HP',bg="red",fg="white",command=checklife)
checklifebutton.pack()


master.mainloop()
```

instead of running the program prints out this in the console

```
attackbutton = Button(text='Attack',bg="black",fg='White',command=attack)
NameError: name 'attack' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of the class.

Comment: Expand on this please, give an example